# Unity 2D: Rigidbody2D.velocity doesn't move character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a 2D player controller and it worked until the day after I made a follow camera script, and now my character can't move but the animation still works. I tried using AddForce() instead of changing Rigidbody2D.velocity but that didn't work either, and after 2 or 3 days I still couldn't find a solution. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;




public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    Animator animator;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    float direction;

    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        direction = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb2d=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -199, 197), 
        transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) && ((Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("d")) || Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("a")))
        {
            speed = 20f;
            run();
        }
        else if (!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) && (Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("d")))
        {
            speed = 10f;
            walk();
        }
        else if (!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)) && (Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("a")))
        {
            speed = 10f;
            walk();
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 0f;
            animator.Play("Player_idle");
        }
    }  

    void walk()
    {
        if (speed > 0) {
            animator.Play("Player_walk_right");
        }
        else if (speed < 0)
        {
            animator.Play("Player_walk_left");
        }
        //rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, rb2d.velocity.y);
        Debug.Log(rb2d.velocity);
    }

    void run()
    { 
        if (speed > 0)
        {
            animator.Play("Player_run_right");
        }

        else if (speed < 0)
        {
            animator.Play("Player_run_left");
        }

        //rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, rb2d.velocity.y);
        Debug.Log(rb2d.velocity);
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the inspector

[image]

If someone could help that would be appreciated.

Comment: `speed * direction * Time.deltaTime` seems to be giving you 0. Try to remove `Time.deltaTime` and check what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your code, the problematic statement should be here:

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed * direction * Time.deltaTime, rb2d.velocity.y);
```

One of these three variables must be zero to cause your problem.

### Potential Problem 1: `direction`

You seem to only be setting `direction` once, in `Start()`:

```
direction = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

You are probably not pressing any keys/moving any joysticks the frame that the scene starts up. That means `direction` ends up being 0 and is never changed again.

Either change your line to

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, rb2d.velocity.y);
```

(excluding `direction`) or move the direction assignment statement to your `Update()` method.

### Potential Problem 2: `Time.deltaTime`

As said by @Daniel in the comments, the `Time.deltaTime` statement might be problematic.

1. Check your project settings/other scripts to make sure `Time.timeScale` is not equal to zero.
2. You could remove `Time.deltaTime` if #1 doesn't work, but I agree with you that the statement should be in there to keep the game consistent across framerates. Try changing  `Update()` to [`FixedUpdate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html); if you do this you will need to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead.

### How to debug in the future

To debug this problem in the future, try inserting a breakpoint at the problematic line and attaching your IDE to Unity. If you hover over each of the variables, you should be able to see which variable is equal to zero.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work for some reason. My main camera also keeps moving up by itself little by little then goes down to where it started. When I press the right and left keys which make the character walk, the character moves like a half a centimeter in the opposite direction that it's supposed to and then it doesn't move anymore, this happened when I moved the direction assignment to Update(). When I removed Time.deltaTime, changed Update() to FixedUpdate(), and changed Time.deltaTime to Time.fixedDeltaTime, it still didn't work.

Comment: If it moves a little bit, that probably means you need to adjust your Rigidbody2D settings. Check your Drag, and check the friction of the Physics Materials you're using.

Comment: My linear drag is 0 and my angular drag is 0.05. The material is None (Physics Material 2D). For constraints I enabled freeze rotation but I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem